# Browsers giving wrong readings for MovementX

Tags: javascript, three.js, cannon.js

I'm currently making a simple fps movement based game in three.js using cannon.js physics.
But I've run into a problem with my first person controls

```
function onMouseMove( event ) {
    if ( scope.isLocked === false ) return;
    const movementX = event.movementX || event.mozMovementX || event.webkitMovementX || 0;
    const movementY = event.movementY || event.mozMovementY || event.webkitMovementY || 0;
    scope.euler.y -= movementX * scope.rotationSpeed;
    scope.euler.x -= movementY * scope.rotationSpeed;
    scope.euler.x = Math.min(Math.max(scope.euler.x, -1.0472), 1.0472);
    camera.quaternion.setFromEuler(scope.euler);
    scope.dispatchEvent( _changeEvent );
}
```

movementX will sometimes give a false reading which is much higher then it should be, and I believe this is down to the browser. I've tested this on both Chrome and Firefox and each will give drastically wrong results every so often.

I'm hoping that there is another more accurate way to get mousemovement besides using event.MovementX

also I'm using `document.body.requestPointerLock();`
which is locking the mouse to the center of the screen.